How to share custom data between devices?
Say I have a button in a specific view controller of my app, that will trigger a function upon receiving an array (for instance an array of Int), in my case I want to playback this array of Ints as pitches for a music chord.
I want users to be able to share this type of array between them, how would I proceed ?
Is there a way to create an app-specific file with custom extension to do so, or would a JSON file be enough, or something else ?
For instance I created a struct like this :
struct ChordItem : {
var name: String = ""
var pitches: [Int] = []
}

I want to be able to export it via a share button, and send it or airdrop it to an other device that would open it in the specific viewcontroller the button is in, it would change the button title automatically to the struct's "name" var and when pressing the button it would playback the "pitches" var via a function I already created that's fired when the button is pressed.
So I don't know how to do this, whether I should create a specific type of file, a JSON, or something else ?
I guess the view controller would need to have a var = ChordItem() in the view controller that would store the received data (maybe thanks to a notification observer?), but I don't know how to proceed to share them between devices...
